# Javascript - Getting 'undefined' when trying to get array's prototype

Tags: javascript, prototype

I think its a 5am brain drain, but I'm having trouble with understanding this.

```
obj = ['a','b'];
alert( obj.prototype ); //returns "undefined"
```

Why isn't `obj.prototype` returning function `Array(){ }` as the prototype? It does reference `Array` as the constructor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because the instance doesn't have a prototype, the class* does.

Possibly you want `obj.constructor.prototype` or alternatively `obj.constructor==Array`

* *to be more accurate, the **constructor** has the prototype, but of course in JS functions = classes = constructors*

Comment: Nah, that isn't it either. alert( obj.constructor.prototype ); returns nothing.

Comment: no, it returns the prototype.toString() - notice how this isn't null, and is not the same thing as returnign nothing - that is the correct reference, what you're doing with it may not be

Comment: Ok, so I think I'm understanding. So obj = 'a', obj = {a:'a'}, obj = ['a'], obj = 0 have no prototypes because they are instances.

But, obj = function(){} returns "[object Object]" for its prototype

Comment: because function is a constructor so it has a prototype - functions are basically the only things you'll get a prototype reference on, whether those are native functions or your own

Comment: long story short - functions are special in JS :D

Comment: So I'm wondering why this doesn't work:

    obj = function(){ return 'obj'; }
    obj2 = new obj();
 
    alert( obj2() ); //says obj2 is not a function

Comment: obj2 is a new instance of the class type obj which in this case is essentially an empty object *not* a function (the return is irrelevant in this usage). If you wrote obj.prototype.foo = function(){return "foo";} then you could create obj2 as a new obj and call obj2.foo(), but not obj.foo();

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you can access the `prototype` object from an instance of an object. The following behaviour might help you:

```
alert(Array); // displays "function Array() { [native code] }"
alert(Array.prototype); // displays ""
alert(['a','b'].constructor); // displays "function Array() { [native code] }"
```

`obj.prototype` isn't returning `function Array() { ... }` as that is the object's constructor.

Comment: ‘constructor’ isn't really reliable; it's not present on IE, and has a subtly different behaviour to what it looks like it's doing, which breaks many forms of subclassing. Best avoided if possible!

Answer (score 1):

In your example, `obj` is an instance of an `Array`, not the class `Array` itself.

Another way to understand it is that for example, you can't inherit from an *instance* of an object (or class), you can only inherit from the object (or class) itself, which in your example it means that you could inherit from the `Array` object, but not from a direct instance of the Array object such as `obj`.

Comment: Thanks. I tested the idea against other object types and also got the 'undefined' response, so I'm understanding that. The only one that is different is the case of:

     obj = function(){}

This returns [object Object]

Answer (score 1):

According to the ECMA spec, an object's prototype link isn't visible, but most modern browsers (firefox, safari, chrome) let you see it via the `__proto__` property, so try:

```
obj = ['a','b'];
alert( obj.__proto__ );
```

An object also has the `constructor' property set on construction, so you can try:

```
obj = ['a','b'];
alert( obj.constructor.prototype );
```

However, `obj.constructor` can be changed after an object's contruction, as can `obj.constructor.prototype`, without changing the actual prototype pointer of obj.

Answer (score 0):

Not really my cup of tea, but does this way of defining it make "obj" an array?
Tried

```
obj = new Array();
obj[0] = "a";
obj[1] = "b";
```

?

Comment: Tried that too, same thing as the array literal

Comment: An array literal is just a more convenient way of creating an array: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/A_re-introduction_to_JavaScript#Arrays